# Как передать в метод несколько параметров с помощью одного параметра object?

Tags: c#

Услышал такой тезис: "Если у метода более трех параметров, то следует создавать параметр "object", то есть объект, который принимает все эти аргументы как свои поля".

Программировать я начал учиться недавно (2 месяца), и было бы очень интересно узнать, как провернуть такой фокус. Подскажите, пожалуйста, кто в теме. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: создаешь класс с нужными полями и передаешь экземпляр этого класса как аргумент функции

Comment: *"Если у метода более трех параметров, то следует создавать параметр "object", то есть объект, который принимает все эти аргументы как свои поля"* --- вообще тезис некорректный. Да, желательно не допускать "раздутых" параметрами методов. В идеале если нет параметров или один.....НО...создавать объект на >=4 параметров не совсем корректно потому, что объект ради объекта - нехорошо. Главное в параметрах выделить общие составляющие и уже их выделять в подгруппу. Например если передаётся userName, userAge и userEmail, то логично создать и передавать объект `User` со всеми этими полями.

Comment: А если передаются userName, countryName, highwaySpeed - то выделять это в один объект - как-то странно.... (сейчас не беру в учёт всякие DTO и POJO... это другое)

Comment: А ответ, по сути, написал Grundy

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Действительно, ради трех-четырех аргументов выглядит сложновато. Мне казалось, что это должно работать как-то похоже на ключевое слово "params", которое позволяет передавать в метод переменное количество аргументов. Но params передает в метод массив, что иногода может быть ещё более неудобно. Думал, что через object будет лучше, но, видимо, нет...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все данные, которые использует метод для работы, образно можно назвать контекстом выполнения. Сюда входят:

- Обращения к публичным полям и свойствам
- Аргументы

Если вдруг аргументов стало много, задумайтесь о том, а стоило ли всё передавать как аргументы. То что никогда не изменяется, может стать константами. То что не изменяется на время какой-то большой операции можно вынести поля, а сам метод в отдельный класс.

```
public class FileParser
{
    private readonly string _path;
    
    public string[] lines { get; private set; }

    public FileParser(string path)
    {
        _path = path;
    }

    public void Load()
    {
        lines = File.ReadAllLines(_path);
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        File.WriteAllLines(_path, lines);
    }
}
```

Получится

```
var parser = new FileParser("example.txt");
parser.Load();
// ...обработка строк
parser.Save();
```

Здесь получается, что поле `_path` это неизменяемый контекст выполнения. Такие данные нет смысла много раз передавать через аргументы. Проще создать класс с полями и постоянные данные держать там. Таким образом можно сократить количество аргументов.

---

Отвечая прямо на вопрос, скучковать данные в общую группу и передать как один аргумент можно, для этого придется создать класс с полями, заполнить его и передавать его экземпляр как аргумент. Но не уверен, что это было бы удобно во всех случаях.

Например

```
public class Message
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

Такое удобно использовать например так

```
var message = chat.ReceiveMessage();
// ...
chat.SendMessage(message);
```

То есть прием и передача единой структуры данных как одного аргумента.

Comment: Благодарю за развёрнутый ответ! Честно говоря я смутно представляю, что происходит в приведенном Вами коде (не имел ещё дела с программами, у которых было бы более двух классов), но по описанию это сильно напоминает метод рефакторинга "превращение метода в класс"... Из того что я понял - передать в метод несколько параметров в одном можно только вынеся все эти параметры в отдельный класс и передавая в метод его экземпляр. Нужно переварить всё это...)

Comment: @JamesBond ООП поизучайте, это основа основ.

Comment: Изучим, никуда не денемся, причём скоро) Просто тяжеловато всё это представить, учитывая, что мои "программы" обычно состоят максимум из двух классов)

Answer (score 2):

Немного не согласен с коллегой, в плане не стоит мешать в одну кучу понятия класс и структура, в C# это немного разные вещи. Использование POCO классов (Plain Old CLR Object) в качестве аргументов позволяет делать очень много:

1. Вы получаете более лаконичный код не перегруженный большим
   количеством аргументов в коде вызывающем методы.
2. Вы получаете более гибкий инструмент управления перегрузкой, что
   позволяет более тонко управлять поведением.
3. Исчезает проблема с вызовом методов содержащих несколько
   необязательных аргументов.
4. Проще реализовать несколько стратегий поведения при внедрении в
   контенер зависимостей в случаях когда по факту аргументом метода
   является указание о выборе некой стратегии выполнения не содержащей
   фатических данных для обработки.

ПРИМЕР АРГУМЕНТА:

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public bool? IsMarried { get; set; } // не обязательный аргумент
    public decimal? Salary { get; set; } // не обязательный аргумент
}
```

ПРИМЕР ИСПОЛЬЗОВАНИЯ:

```
public void DisplayPersonInfo(Person person)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Full Name: {person.FirstName} {person.LastName}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Age: {person.Age}");
        
        // Вывод информации только если поля установлены
        if (person.IsMarried.HasValue)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Is Married: {person.IsMarried.Value}");
        }
        
        if (person.Salary.HasValue)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Salary: {person.Salary.Value}");
        }
    }
```

Кроме того POCO классы широко используется в WEB фреймворках для инкапсуляции данных передаваемых с фронта в бэк и обратно, например модель привязки ASP.Net.
В общем это удобный подход, который нужно брать на вооружение. В разрезе контекстно ориентированного подхода к проектированию, на основе контекстно ориентированной абстракции, в соотвествии с практиками рекомендуемыми "Бандой четырех", с которыми стоит ознакомиться.

> Паттерны объектно-ориентированного проектирования
> ISBN:9785446115952, 5446115953

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Звучит красиво, но мне бы на уровне циферок и буковок на это посмотреть)) Боюсь, иначе не пойму, не тот уровень пока...(

Comment: Суть метода проста как три копейки и прослеживается в обоих ответах вы используете вместо кучи аргументов один в виде класса с кучей полей. Аргументы функции/метода формируют ее сигнатуру, сигнатура определяет поведение это все что нужно знать по сути.

Comment: Я понял. Значит, пока мне это не поможет...) Это уже больше про грамотную организацию кода в больших программах, а не в моих маленьких консольных приложухах с одним exe-шником и одной dll-кой...)) Спасибо за разъяснения, суть понял, всё запомнил. В будущем обязательно пригодится.

Comment: Не согласен, во первых это полезно даже в маленьких программах, во вторых именно в консольных приложениях аргументы часто передаются как ключи в параметрах запуска и что бы не мучатся с порядком их обработки в массиве можно на первом этапе затолкать их в объект и работать с ним как вариант. В любом случае это шаг к принципу единственной отвественности отдельных частей кода который нужно строить без великого "paste and copy" принцип чистого кода. Лучше сразу учится делать правильно но по своему и выработать свой стиль но понятный другим.

Comment: Тут есть одна загвоздка. В курсе, по которому я учусь, преподаватель наставивает на том, что статические поля нужно использовать только в крайних случаях, и лучше всегда обходиться без них. Аргументирует вполне здраво - например, что связь того или иного поля с каким-то методом нельзя понять, не заглянув в этот метод и не поняв, что он это поле изменяет или использует его значение. Это ухудшает читаемость кода и нарушает его логику. Так что прежде чем замахиваться на передачу классов в методы, нужно сначала с полями разобраться - как же их всё таки использовать, и в каких случаях.

Comment: Боюсь что вы путаете понятия очень сильно, POCO класс не имеет ничего общего с тем о чем вы говорите и уж точно не является статическим, это способ достичь изоляции на уровне абстракции вашего приложения, обеспечить реализацию аспектов поведения без углубления в детали возможной реализации, совместно с интерфейсами в C# POCO классы используются для реализации контрактов взаимодействия, обеспечивающих независисомть функциональности от фактической реализации. Статические же поля напротив нарушают инкапсуляцию реализации прибивая вас гвоздями к контексту и проблемам с консистентностью.

Comment: Видимо, мы просто о каких-то разных полях говорим) Да, пока не в теме. Ну, тогда, если подытожить, то если у нас в методах неразбериха с аргументами, мы можем создать класс и сложить все эти переменные туда как поля (будет чисто класс для полей), а в методы просто передавать экземпляр этого класса. Сейчас ещё мысль появилась, что такой класс может выполнять ещё и роль адаптера, т.е. заменять длинные, сложные, или просто дибильные названия на понятные и краткие...
Верно понял?